# Having issues while sending text to a textbox which has onkeypress event using c# selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having a textbox which has onkeypress event which performs a page render when the value is entered to textbox. Here I am using selenium webdriver to fill the textbox. Before filling the textbox I am using textbox.clear(). So the onkeypress event get called  and page gets rendered. So the textbox control is removed from webdriver instance.

After the onkeypress event taking place, the element is not getting listed in the webdriver.
This is the source tag of the particular textbox:

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cphMainContent_wzrDREvent_txtNftnTime" class="OpCenter_DateBox" type="text" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cphMainContent$wzrDREvent$txtNftnTime\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cphMainContent$wzrDREvent$txtNftnTime">
```

And you can see the onkeypress event used here. 
Please suggest some ideas for filling the values in textbox.

I am using the following code to fill my text box:

```
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys(value);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try hitting on backspace for several times (using win32 ole) and then send the text maybe? I dunno mate it seems that you are really STUCK!

Comment: I think u have mistook my question. I am using Selenium web driver and doing the automation test. I cant hit backspace while test is running.

Comment: Can you please provide the Selenium code you are currently using to send input to the input box you have posted?

Comment: " textbox control is removed from webdriver instance" - what do you meanby webdriver instance ?  what exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following JavaScript code to overcome this issue.

```
if (!(webDriver.GetType().FullName).Contains("IE"))
            {
                // To stop the page postback in Firefox and chrome
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("window.stop();");
            }
```

The above code stops the page load and it works perfectly.

However, in Firefox 23.0 and above, this JavaScript is not working. Otherwise, for Chrome 31.0 and IE 9, the JavaScript works fine.

Comment: Wouldn't stopping a postback be modifying the application behavior?

Comment: @Faiz : The application behaviour needs to be like that. It should have a postback event while changing the test text box.

Comment: exactly - when you use `window.stop()`, you are stopping the application from doing what it should. The postback is there for a reason - for eg: it might be performing some validation; you should not stop it to suit your testing.

Comment: @Faiz: My application's postback behaviour is to validate the time am going to give. I already giving a valid time stamp. In this scenario, my scope is not to validate the time stamp which I am giving. So I need to get rid of this postback in order to achieve my result.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking at the `onchange` event being fired when you perform `clear()`.

A solution is to clear and set text in one action, rather than in separate calls. You can do this by using the `Actions` class, the below C# extension method shows how.

The onchange event will fire once you lose focus from the text field element.

```
public static class WebElementExtensions
{
 public void ClearAndSetText(this IWebElement element, string text)
 {
    Actions navigator = new Actions(driver);
        navigator.Click(element)
            .SendKeys(Keys.End)
            .KeyDown(Keys.Shift)
            .SendKeys(Keys.Home)
            .KeyUp(Keys.Shift)
            .SendKeys(Keys.Backspace)
            .SendKeys(text)
            .Perform();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS injection is not a wise solution all the time, i would suggest you to go with @Faiz.Also, writing a code for a scenario specific or page specific will give you tremendous pain in maintenance phase.