# Selenium Webdriver unable to access web element on Internet Explorer 8 - shown as disabled

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver

Setup Details:
Webdriver 2.39
IEDriverServer 2.39

I'm running Selenium automation on an internal site. The code works fine on Firefox 27 but there's an issue on IE8

I'm trying to first clear and enter text in a text field on IE. This fails on IE with the error "Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only." I checked the element properties on IE and it does indeed show enabled as False, even though the element is plainly available. On Firefox, enabled is correctly set to True.

I've tried to use Xpath and sendkeys but they don't work. Here what I tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='tagName']")).Clear(); - not working
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='tagName']")).SendKeys(tagName); - not working
driver.FindElement(By.Id("tagName")).SendKeys(Keys.Control); - not working
driver.FindElement(By.Id("tagName")).Clear(); - not working
driver.FindElement(By.Id("tagName")).SendKeys(tagName); - not working
```

Is there some way I can access this element on IE?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: Sounds like IE renders the page differently, so not a Selenium issue to me....you should find out, with the help of the developers, *why* IE is rendering it differently.

Comment: Hi Arran, I agree with you totally and I'll follow up with them about it. Accepting that, is there some way to interact with the element even when it's in a disabled state?

Comment: Whilst you can workaround it using JavaScript, like the other posts mention, that's a workaround, and not a solution to the underlying issue. You will just have to use jQuery or JavaScript to remove the disabled attribute from the element. Post the HTML of what the element looks like in IE and Firefox. You can get a better and more specific answer that way.

Comment: The HTML code is <input type="text" style="width: 90%;" size="50" maxlength="50" value="New Tag" name="tagName" id="tagName" class="myInput">

Comment: I can enter text into the text box using Actions builder like so but I cannot figure out how to first Clear the text. Any ideas? IWebElement textBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tagName"));
builder.MoveToElement(textBox).SendKeys(textBox,"Test").Build().Perform();

Comment: Use clear() before SendKeys()

Comment: @bearaman - to clear using actions, use `SendKeys(Keys.Backspace)` before sending new text. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298233/having-issues-while-sending-text-to-a-textbox-which-has-onkeypress-event-using-c/20233459#20233459)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was the builder object of Selenium. I used this to force the automation to select the textbox and enter test like so:

```
IWebElement searchField = Global.driver.FindElement(by);
builder.Click(searchField).SendKeys(searchField, textToEnter).Perform();
```

This worked!
J.

Answer (score 0):

We frequently test against IE8 and encounter "unique" Selenium issues.

Sometimes we use `ExecuteScript` to bypass Selenium's finicky selectors, and use jQuery to return the element or to manipulate it directly:

```
// Get an element
IWebElement element = (IWebElement) driver.ExecuteScript("return $('#tagName')[0]");

// Clear the value of a field
driver.ExecuteScript("$('input[name=\'tagName\']').val('');");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jabbett but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require changing the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement searchField = Global.driver.FindElement(by);
builder.Click(searchField).SendKeys(searchField, textToEnter).Perform();
```

****its working but sending wrong text to the field. 
For ex: i have to send "11-12-2015" and it is sending "28-12-2015". 
Any Clue what's happening when performing inserting action.****